# Define the number of elements of a one-dimensional array based on a variable rather than a constant

Tags: java, arrays

I am little confused at to what based on a variable means. I made an attempt at it not sure if its correct. Is it?

```
int size;
System.out.print("Enter the array size: "); 
size = input.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[size];
```

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Yes a variable is something that isnt known at run time. An array based on a constant would be `int[] arr = new int[10]`. So the difference is we know the size of the array at run time in my example but we dont in your example

Comment: Yeah that code looks right, you are creating an array with a size that can change and used a variable to define the size. Good job!

Comment: Does that code compile? Just wondering because you use slanted/sloped quotation marks instead of straight.

Answer (score 1):

> Define the number of elements of a one-dimensional array based on a
>   variable rather than a constant

You have done it right. lets break up it into parts to clear your confusion.

> Define the number of elements of a one-dimensional array

```
int size;
System.out.print(“Enter the array size: “); 
size = input.nextInt();
```

here you have defined how many elements should be in you array. In simple words size of array.

> based on a variable rather than a constant

you have taken above variable `size` to define the size of length , it is variable means it can have any value which user enters not hard coded in the code.

Hope your confusion is clear.
Well tried mate.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the problem of variable or constant, it is about the confusion of using`new int[size]`.
In fact, it is just a second format of`new int[](size)`, it will new an object which is an array type. And `int` is just a generic parameter.